# How to make segment control work in Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have created custom view like this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView: MKMapView!

    func mapTypeChanged(segControl: UISegmentedControl){
        switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            mapView.mapType = .standard
        case 1:
            mapView.mapType = .hybrid
        case 2:
            mapView.mapType = .satellite
        default:
            break
        }

    }
    override func loadView() {
        mapView = MKMapView()

        view = mapView

        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Standard", "Hybrid", "Satellite"])

        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

            segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "mapTypeChanged", for: .valueChanged)


        segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(segmentedControl)

        let topConstraint = segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8)

        let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide

        let leadingContraint = segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor)

        let trailingConstraint = segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor)

        topConstraint.isActive = true
        leadingContraint.isActive = true
        trailingConstraint.isActive = true

    }

}
```

There are no build issues. but when I run the app and tap on any button on segmented control, it aborts the app. Not able to figure out what is the issue. I am using Xcode 9 beta.

Comment: I guess `loadView` is not called at all and the map view is `nil`. Maybe you mean `viewDidLoad`

Comment: loadView is called and map is displayed. app crashes when I try to change the type of map.

Comment: What error do you get? Unknown selector?

Comment: thread 1: SIGABRT

Comment: This is not an error message. That is a general message that an exception occurred

Comment: app hangs up. no button works when I tap on any segmented control

Comment: Press the `continue` button in the debugger to get the error message and the stack trace.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the way you are setting selector is causing the issue 
change it to

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapTypeChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

And add @IBAction to your mapTypeChanged like

```
@IBAction func mapTypeChanged(segControl: UISegmentedControl) {
```

Comment: yeah. Thats because to bind it at runtime you will need Obj C runtime.In Swift 4 this was a change that it will never take implicitly Obj C runtime, everything that uses Obj C runtime needs to be explicitly mentioned. So that programmer and reader knows that this is going to be bound at runtime to some event.

Comment: apple documentation is confusing here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget

Comment: instead of \@objc, try using \@IBAction, that should also work. I am not on my machine to try things out.

Comment: thats because @IBActions also uses Obj C runtime. GREAT learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is a hybrid of the other two.

`segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapTypeChanged:), for: .valueChanged)`